# Post Loop showing on one page but not a different page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, post

I have my main homepage, and then I have a duplicate of it translated in French. The code for both pages is identical, but for some reason the latest post section is only showing on the English version, and not the French. The area I'm referring to is about halfway down the page, and on the French version, it is just a white box with the word "Blog" inside.

English: https://dvat.artrageousdemo.com/
French: https://dvat.artrageousdemo.com/fr/

Here is the code being used to pull the latest post. It is working for 1 of the 2 pages even though it's on both.

```
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'order'          => 'ASC'
    ) );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            ?>
                            <span><?php the_time( 'jS F, Y' ); ?></span>
                            <h6><?php the_title(); ?></h6>
                            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='learn-btn'>Learn More <img src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/a2.png' alt=''></a>
        <?php endwhile; endif;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Learn more` isn't translatable. Is that what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

For the other language post you need to pass `'suppress_filters' => true` in WP_Query argument.

Here I have shared the example for your reference:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'suppress_filters' => true
    ) );
```

I hope it would be helpful.